# How to connect an existing MQTT broker with Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I have a site using html, php, javascript and css in which I add my data from IOT devices using MQTT broker. Now I want to update it and I want to connect my MQTT broker with Thingsboard MQTT to manage the same data from both platforms. How can I succeed the communication between the two MQTT brokers?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "[Thingsboard IoT Gateway](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/)". In the Gateway you can set your external MQTT Broker and connect it over the Gateway to Thingsboard. I think thats the only solution. Just follow the instructions.